# Twitter card shown in twitter card validator but not on twitter feed

Tags: html, twitter, webforms

I am working on a c# webforms project and im using twitter cards to send image and description of the website.

in the validator the card displays correctly. I just get the yellow warning that "this card is redirected "url"". im not really sure if it affects if it displays or not. But when i post to my feed nothing shows. Just the text i write by myself from a tweet popup where you have to sign in if you arent logged into twitter.

this page uses routing and login so if you try to access a page where you have to be logged in you will be redirected to login page.

but the validator works both for the startpage and for your own pages . The twitter card tags are added dynamically in the master.cs

Any idea of what i should look for to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

This might be easy to miss if you don't look for it. But there should be a link on the bottom right of your tweet that reads 'View details' (or 'view photo', or others depending on the card type). Twitter cards are not shown expanded on the feed.

See some examples here: https://twitter.com/HTMLAtSo
The 'view summary' link must be followed to view the expanded Summary Card

Comment: So basically we just post a tweet and always add the URL to the twitter card? It's kind of hit and miss with my twitter cards. They all validate alright, but when I post with a twitter card URL, I don't always see the "View Details" link.

Any ideas or suggestions? 

PS: Yes, I have read the Twitter Cards API. ;-)

Comment: @Shawn Are all of those URLs accessible? Also make sure you're adding the URL in the data-url attribute, not in the tweet itself. Not sure what else could be wrong, maybe show some example tweets?